# How to properly run filter/search/order operation on composite entity derived from multiple EF models?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, search

I have an ASP.NET MVC project where data is presented in a standard "table" format, with the ability to apply filters or to search for among certain columns and to sort the final results. Each individual entry in the table is currently 
represented as a view model. For example:

```
EntryViewModel

string Name
int ArmCount
DateTime DateOfBirth 
bool IsMammal
```

Each entry can trace its source to one of two EF models. Each model has its own way of mapping to an `EntryViewModel`. For example:

```
Animal

string Name
virtual Collection<Member> Members <-- Navigation Property
int Age
bool IsVertebrate 
bool IsColdBlooded
```

---

```
Human

string FirstName
string LastName
virtual BodyInfo Body <-- Navigation Property
```

---

```
EntryViewModel <--> Animal

Name =        Name
ArmCount =    Members.Where(m => m.Type == Arm).Count()
DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now - Age 
IsMammal =    IsVertebrate && !IsColdBlooded
```

---

```
EntryViewModel <--> Human

Name =        FirstName + LastName
ArmCount =    Body.Arms.Count()
DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now - Body.Age 
IsMammal =    true
```

---

Keep in mind that there are a lot more properties on the actual EF models. Most of them (especially the ones that are computed from navigation property fields) are not actually used when searching and filtering the data entries.

The search logic is currently performed on the resulting `EntryViewModel` entities. The issue is that the initial EF models have to be translated into the full `EntryViewModel` before the search and filter predicates are applied. This seems gives the query very poor performance.

How could I make it so that my search predicates are applied to "computed" columns without having to fully map each separate model to its `EntryViewModel` 
 representation? If we relate to the previous examples, my goal would be to only compute or use the final 'Name' for both entities, without materializing the other properties until after I know which entries will be included.

Note that I am using EF5 model first with  lazy loading is enabled.

Comment: Any reason why you do the search on the VMs instead of the original models?

Comment: Because they represent the final conceptual representation of the data. The user will see a 'Name' column, and so will search using this representation. The original models might not even have a concept of a 'Name'.